# Django Combine Many Unrelated Models on Related Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have 3 models T, E, Q such that:

```
class E(Model):
    name_e = CharField()

class T(Model):
    name_t = CharField()
    e = ForeignKey(E)

class Q(Model):
    name_q = CharField()
    e = ForeignKey(E)
```

I also have Serializers for each:

```
class ESerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = E
        fields = '__all__'

class TSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    e = ESerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = T
        fields = '__all__'

class QSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    e = ESerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Q
        fields = '__all__'
```

For one E row there can be many T and Q rows.
I can make a query such that

```
t = T.objects.filter(e__id=1).all()
serialized_t = TSerializer(t, many=True).data
```

And the output of `serialized_t` will look something like:

```
[
 {id:7, name_t:'test_1', e:{id:1, name_e:'ename_1'}},
 {id:9, name_t:'test_2', e:{id:1, name_e:'ename_1'}}
]
```

My question is how could I combine it so that I can include Q in the query above to create an output for the T query which would also include all Q's where e_id=1 and hence it would look something like this:

```
[
 {id:7, name_t:'test_1', e:{id:1, name_e:'ename_1'}, q:[{id:4, name_q:'qname_1'}, {id:5, name_q:'qname_2'}]},
 {id:9, name_t:'test_2', e:{id:1, name_e:'ename_1'}, q:[{id:4, name_q:'qname_1'}, {id:5, name_q:'qname_2'}]}
]
```

I don't mind if this can be done in-query itself, or if it involves some appending to the SerializedT object, as long as I have a serialized result at the end of it which matches my needs that I can send as a JSON object as an API response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by writing `T` serializer like this:

```
class TSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    e = ESerializer()
    q = QInTSerializer(source='e.q_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = T
        fields = '__all__'
```

This will build a `q` field that represents a list of `Q` objects. Specifying `source='e.q_set'` is for telling the field where to look for those list of `Q`s from the `T` instance being serialized (in this case, all `Q`'s related to `T`'s `E`).

But you also have to write another `Q` serializer to not display the `E` within `Q` (only `id` and `name_q` as required):

```
class QInTSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Q
        fields = ('id', 'name_q')
```

You can also save on DB hits if you plan to serialize multiple `T` objects by selecting the related `E` object, and prefetching the related `Q` objects from `E`:

```
t = T.objects.select_related('e').prefetch_related('e__q_set')
```

Comment: Thanks @BrianD could you explain what `e.q_set` represents? Because trying the above I am getting an error `'E' object has no attribute 'q_set'`

Comment: It's to access the `Q` objects from `T`. Much like `t = T.objects.first(); t.e.q_set.all()`. `q_set` is the related name to access q from e.